# Intellij Idea: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Even though my user is on docker group and I can launch `docker` without `sudo`, and I'm running `idea.sh` from my user, whenever I try to connect to docker from within Intellij Idea docker plugin, I get

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I'm trying the `Unix socket` method. I already tried multiple restarts and logout.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and Intellijd Idea 2020.3

Comment: (1) Well, _is_ the daemon running? (Does `systemctl` or whatever other process supervision control tool your distro provides say it's running?)

Comment: (2) Does the socket exist on the filesystem?

Comment: (3) Which user and group own that socket? Which user and group are your process in?

Comment: Answers to the above questions might be enough to _start_ trying to answer this. Without that information [edit]ed into the question, any answers would be speculation at best.

Answer (score 17):

For me it work

```
sudo chmod 0777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

[image]

Then test this in the terminal without the sudo

```
docker ps -a
```

normally you should have access to the docker process

Comment: 0666 is enough permissions. Atleast for me.

Comment: **WARNING**: This essentially gives unrestricted root access to any user on your machine. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface

Answer (score 17):

toggling (off and on) "Allow the default Docker socket to be used" checkbox with "Apply & restart" (2 times) in Docker Desktop helped me

[image: docker desctop]

Comment: Thanks @kurama this saved me so much heartache!

Answer (score 10):

Adding current user to docker group worked for me:

```
sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
```

You might need to create group first:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

**restart your OS after those changes**

Comment: this approach has major security implications: it effectively makes your user root. see https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sudo systemctl unmask docker && sudo systemctl start docker
```